# Different ways of writing the empty set

Tags: typography

What (possibly sarcastic) ways of writing the empty set in TeX do you know?

Here are some examples: `\text{\O}`, `\emptyset`, `\not O`, `\varphi`, `\varnothing`, `\phi`.

This renders as: [image]

Comment: it isn't clear what your question is, `\text{\O}`, `\not O`, `\varphi`, `\phi`  are clearly wrong. `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` are both correct, just a matter of personal style preference.

Comment: Notice the "possibly sarcastic" in parentheses. This is supposed to be a soft question.

Comment: I thought of `{}` (like in my other (empty) comment). Is there a `Cheshire` set symbol (as in the quantum cat's great grandparent)?  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few more examples of ways to write the empty set in TeX:

{} - this uses the curly braces notation for sets, but with no elements inside the braces.

\boxed{} - this uses the \boxed command to create a box around the empty set.

\big{\big} - this uses the \big command to create larger curly braces around the empty set.

\left{\right} - this uses the \left and \right commands to create dynamic curly braces that adjust to the size of the empty set.

\varnothing_{\text{Nothing}} - this uses the \varnothing symbol to represent the empty set, and adds a subscript to clarify that it represents "Nothing."

\text{Nada} - this uses the \text command to write the word "Nada" as a representation of the empty set.

{\text{\tiny No elements here}} - this uses the \tiny command to make the text inside the curly braces very small, and adds a message to clarify that the set has no elements.

\text{Void} - this uses the \text command to write the word "Void" as a representation of the empty set.

{\text{\Large Nothing}} - this uses the \Large command to make the text inside the curly braces very large, and adds the word "Nothing" to clarify that the set has no elements.

Please note that some of these examples may be sarcastic or humorous in nature, and may not be suitable for all types of documents.